Why must the high priest enter the Most Holy Place twice on the Day of Atonement?
In Leviticus 16:15, after atoning for the priesthood inside the Most Holy Place using bull blood, Aaron is instructed to exit the sanctuary, sacrifice the Lord's goat, and enter the Most Holy Place again, atoning again using goat's blood this time (for the people). After this, he performs further atonement for the Tent of Meeting and the altar of sacrifice. Based on Leviticus 16:18, it appears that this is done with both blood types at the same time. Why did the high priest need to finish the bull offering's MHP atonement before performing Israel's MHP sacrifice and atonement? Couldn't he have killed the bull and the goat at the same time and brought their blood in at the same time? If the rites were meant to be separate, it makes more sense to me that he would wait until all three compartments are atoned for (MHP, tent, altar) with bull blood before beginning with goat blood.
Also, if it helps anybody process it, it appears that the sacrificial goat and live goat were determined in between the Most Holy Place atonements. 16:6, which is cited in 16:11, is followed with the selection of the two goats. Hence, the goats are selected in after the bull offering's atonement, in between the two MHP atonements.

In verses 11-14 he sacrifices the bull and goes in and offers it in the MHP. Then in v. 15 he has to sacrifice and go into the veil again, meaning he went out of the MHP.

The bull is offered on the altar of burnt offering  - only the blood is sprinkled near the Ark of the Covenant/mercy seat/atonement cover

Correct. To clarify: (16:11) Sacrifice of the bull. (16:12-13) Enter the MHP. (16:14) Sprinkle bull blood on the mercy seat & around it. (16:15) Go back to the courtyard (implicit), sacrifice the goat, go back into the MHP, and do with its blood as he did with the bull's. My question is why he had to split up the sacrifices. Couldn't he have performed atoning rites at the same time? He seems to perform bull and goat atonement simultaneously in 16:18, and implicitly in 16:16b.
